# Adding schema.org to site

Tags: seo, schema.org

I want to add schema.org to my site, I've read some guides for that and I understood the way I should do that. But should I add these tags for example for images and url:

```html
<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <a itemprop="contentUrl"  href="someurl" rel="bookmark">
    <img  src="someurl"/>
  </a>

</figure>
```

to all my images, all my urls, all my pages or there is a way to do that globally for my site?

Comment: Scheme exists exactly for the fact that it's difficult to extract meta data from only pure markup and it needs human to decorate them with the meta data. If there was a global automated way, probably crawlers would have adopted it so you wouldn't have to deal with scheme

Comment: So, I should add it everywhere, my project has many files...

Comment: Indeed if you have a static site without reusable components then you would have to do it manually for each section of your content. Number of files in a project does not necessarily need to increase the work for adding scheme, if those files are being used within reusable components which hold the meta data as attributes

Comment: My site is dynamic, I can add these tags in my loop for elements. But there are different dynamic pages, I should add this example code in my question for all places that I have images ?

Comment: You have to design the scheme for each dynamic.m section one by one. Use the scheme validator too. Many types of content needs scheme decoration. Addresses, business, articles, images etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are meant to be added to all your tags. That way you show search engines the semantic relationship between every item on your webpage.

If you don't use any programming or frameworks, you need to add them by hand.

It is a good practice to always validate them while developing to see how Search Engines will see them: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: Thank you, all! I'll have to add it everywhere! Yes, I found this tool for testing! :)